# When trying to assing a input character to my struct the program chrashes

Tags: c, scanf

As a new Student in programming I am trying to make a program which will take input from the user and save it to a struct which will later be saved to a file, everything except the user input part is working, but here the first 2 parts work as intended (name and surname which are arrays)

```
printf("And what about down below? are you a man or a woman? <M/F>\n");
scanf(" %c", user_profile.gender);
```

is the part that crashes my program

the struct is assigned outside any functions to make it global here

```
struct profile_info
{
char first_name[30];
char last_name[30];
char gender;
int age;
int height;
double weight;
};
```

lastly i make a placeholder in my main() I dont knw if this is required though

```
strcpy(user_profile.first_name, "placeholder");
strcpy(user_profile.last_name, "placeholder");
user_profile.gender = 't';
user_profile.age = 5;
user_profile.height = 5;
user_profile.weight = 5;
```

the assignment is happening inside a function which is called by a function which is called by main() if that has any relevance

also the placeholder, is created in main

---

** **UPDATE** **

The problem has been solved (look answer 1)
however a new problem has risen when trying to scan back form the file using facanf resulting the the following

I've tried using `fscanf()` however to no avail the first 2 lines a read

```
    /* this function will load the user profile if such a profile exists */
    void user_profile_loader(struct profile_info user_profile)
    {
    FILE *file_pointer;
    int i;
    file_pointer = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    fscanf(file_pointer, user_profile.first_name);

    fscanf(file_pointer, user_profile.last_name);

    fscanf(file_pointer, &(user_profile.gender));

    fscanf(file_pointer, &(user_profile.age));

    fscanf(file_pointer, &(user_profile.height));

    fscanf(file_pointer, &(user_profile.weight));

    printf("%s \n%s \n€c \n%d \n%d \n%lf", user_profile.first_name, user_profile.last_name,
    user_profile.gender, user_profile.age, user_profile.height, user_profile.weight);
}
```

however, i need help specefieng which lines should be read (1 thorugh 6) which i tried first using

```
    /* this function will load the user profile if such a profile exists */
    void user_profile_loader(struct profile_info user_profile)
    {
    FILE *file_pointer;
    int i;
    file_pointer = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    fscanf(file_pointer, 1, user_profile.first_name);

    fscanf(file_pointer, 2, user_profile.last_name);

    fscanf(file_pointer, 3, &(user_profile.gender));

    fscanf(file_pointer, 4, &(user_profile.age));

    fscanf(file_pointer, 5, &(user_profile.height));

    fscanf(file_pointer, 6, &(user_profile.weight));

    printf("%s \n%s \n€c \n%d \n%d \n%lf", user_profile.first_name, user_profile.last_name,
    user_profile.gender, user_profile.age, user_profile.height, user_profile.weight);
}
```

neither one works, and the current one (1st one) gives me an error

```
In file included from introduktion.c:1:0:
(my directory) stdio.h:385:15: note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'int'
int __cdec1 fscanf(FILE * __restrict__ _File,const char * __restrict__ _Format,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
```

and

passing argument 2 of fscanf makes pointer from integer without a cast
so it doesnt understand what input it gets?

Comment: You should post the code instead of adding screenshots.

Comment: Show your code (as text), please, no photos. This is not Instagram.

Comment: Sorry for this :-) just figured out he correct way to input code, the fll post has been edited :-)

Comment: I'd call it "sex" rather than "gender" (let's talk about it on StackAntropology).

Comment: @MOehm, it's fixed now :-) had some problems firguring out the formatting, the problem has been solved, however i have hit a new error when trying to load back the files, should i make a new post or edit the current one? :-)

Comment: Please look above comment @Arc676 :-)

Comment: @NikolajLjørring: No need to delete the post; the post looks good now. And you've already gotten an answer.

Comment: @MOehm, yes, and it worked like i hoped :-) however, when trying to load the information back from the file my fscanf returns an error which is 2 sided, first it posts the error which i cantmake sense of, then it post some code fomr stdio.h line 385, so my questions is if i should make a new post with the new question or just edit it into this one and see if people notice :-)

Comment: Oh, yes, new problem, new post. It is better to open  a fresh question, because (a) the original problem has already been solved and (b) adding and editing pots repeatedly is confusing and might even invalidate some answers and comments. (You can link to this post in reference, if you like, so that people don't go: Huh? Haven't I seen this before?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,

```
scanf(" %c", user_profile.gender);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c", &(user_profile.gender));
             ^
```

You need to supply the *address* of the variable as the argument to the format specifier.

Read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for more info on `scanf()`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! 
could you explain to me why this is? Is it because the argument is passed multiple times it is a pointer and then to  select a speceifc child in the struct i need to assign it to the addres (since it's a pointer? or am i just talking shit, still very new to this :-)

Comment: @NikolajLjørring _"...the results from such conversions, if any, are stored in the locations **pointed to by the pointer** arguments that follow format. "_

Comment: I see! thnaks a bucnh, I've encountered a new problem which i can't make sense of, the compiler prints out something from stdio.h, since i can't ask a new question for 90 mins, would you mind looking at the following?

`In file included from introduktion.c:1:0:
(my directory) stdio.h:385:15: note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'int'
    int __cdec1 fscanf(FILE * __restrict__ _File,const char * __restrict__ _Format,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;`

Comment: which is followed by `passing argument 2 of fscanf from incompatible pointer type` or `expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type int`

Which would suggest that fscanf only takes in strings, however i couldn't fint anything on this